# Return variable from interpolate function in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, interpolation

Is there a way to return values in react native from the an interpolate. Instead of running an additional state through the app I want to use the existing interpolated value and then return true or false based on its current value.

The animated value however is not an actual number that can be stored outside the native driver (as far as I can see) and obviously you can't do the following but the following is what I am essentially trying to achieve.

```
var Active = this.props.status.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-1, 0, 1],
    outputRange: [false, true, false],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important thing to remember that the code like you posted is only run once on every render. It is essentially a declaration for interpolation

```
 const backgroundColor = position.interpolate({
   inputRange: [0, 100],
   outputRange: ['red', 'blue'],
  });

 //

 <View style={{ backgroundColor }} />
```

If, lets say, your render is called once, it doesn't stop your view from changing background color in the future in response to animated value change even though this render might never be called again. So would it help you to know the value of this animatable just once? Even if you could get it like this, you would not get an updated value next time it changes (unless your render is triggered for some other unrelated reason). The value is not reactive and will almost always be of no use for rendering purposes

The correct way of doing this is attaching a listener to animated value

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.status.interpolate.addListener(({ value }) => {
    console.log('new value: ', value)
    this.lastKnownValue = value
  })
}
```

this will notify you every time value changes. If you still want to access this value in render, just store it somewhere (in class property of class based component, or in a [ref container](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) of a functional component) and read it from there during render